# juju not able to spin up lxd container

Tags: lxd, juju

currently I'm trying to setup a three node `mysql-innodb-cluster` on a maas-deployment using juju.

The setup process worked flawlessly and the deployment of other charms worked fine. When deploying the cluster I would like to achieve that in separate `lxd`-container. But that doesn't work. I get the error:

[image: debug-log]

Did I miss some critical configuration step here?

Answer (score 0):

did you turn OFF ipv6? that is generally needed when setting up LXD & Juju.. you do that in the `lxd init` prompts

if you can, you need to wipe all the machine or at the least your network bridges for LXD

Comment: No the Problem was that my subnet was way too big for juju to handle correctly. After applying a **/24** subnet mask everything worked fine.